# Unable to use any angular tag in html file due to error "Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-spinner'"

Tags: angular, angular10

I am new to angular and trying to get familiar with angular 10, using [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-10-crud-application-tutorialexample.html) tutorial. I have followed all the steps from this tutorial but stuck at step-8. Whenever i run the app, it show
**Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-spinner'.** and
**Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-spinner'.** error in browser console.
I have checked some SO posts and add **CommonModule** and **BrowserModule** in posts.module.ts file, but its still not working. I am not able to figure it out.
Here is my **posts.module.ts** file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { PostRoutingModule } from './post-routing.module';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [IndexComponent, ViewComponent, CreateComponent, EditComponent],
  imports: [
    PostRoutingModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatCardModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
})
export class PostModule {}
```

This is my **posts-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'post', redirectTo: 'post/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'post/index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'post/:postId/view', component: ViewComponent },
  { path: 'post/create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: 'post/:postId/edit', component: EditComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PostRoutingModule {}
```

This is my **index.component.html** file

```
<div style="padding: 13px;">

  <mat-spinner *ngIf="posts.length === 0"></mat-spinner>

  <mat-card *ngFor="let post of posts" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{post.id}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>{{post.title}}
      </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>
        {{post.body}}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-button> Buy product</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

This is error in console

[image]

This is my project structure

[image]

Comment: Is post module actually in app module..?

Comment: Remove `BrowserModule` from `posts.module.ts` this should only be declared in your `appModule` and then any other modules should use `CommonModule`.

Comment: @MikeOne I have added it to app.module as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `BrowserModule` from `posts.module.ts` this should only be declared in your `appModule` and then any other modules should use `CommonModule`

Comment: Removing it make no difference, still getting same error.

Comment: Is it just posts/index that has the spinner in it?

Comment: Yes, this is the only page with spinner